# jsPDF rendering a simple string

Tags: pdf-generation, jspdf

I am going through jsPDF. while it seems like a good library it is missing good documentation.

I have written a pretty simple code but it doesn't seems to print anything. Everytime it generates a blank pdf. Below is my code, if any one have any idea please help me out.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','in','a4')  
pdf.setFontSize(40);
pdf.text(35,25,'vvdfv sdv sdf sfdsf df sfsf')
pdf.save('dynamic pdf-examples.pdf');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you've set your units to inches and 35 inches is way off the page. You can either change your unit of measurement (to mm perhaps?) or lower the numbers.

You're right about the documentation - it's something I'm going to be working on soon.

Comment: wow James Hall himself :) ...i thought of using this library to convert the reporting page(which contains html5 graphs) in an application to pdf. But for this I have now found that it is very easy to convert a canvas to image using toDataUrl(), this image can then be used to build pdf. BTW this is the small library I wrote for HTML5 graphs  https://code.google.com/p/simple-jquery-linear-graph/